# datapacks are not fetched in Vlocity IDX Workbench

Tags: salesforce

I am working on Vlocity IDX Workbench, I've configured the repository, source and target.In new project popup window, it is not showing any datapacks. in the logs it shows SOQL error.
Please assist.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1hkg.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in the post

1. SOQL error when connecting with the dev org
2. Path error when retrieving Salesforce components.
   For the 1st error I've not got the solution but as a workaround I am using my Project's sandbox and it is retrieving the vlocity datapacks.
   for the 2nd error the solution is,
   For the first time we need to retrieve only vlocity datapacks and save it so that sfdx-project.json will be created.

This should be avaliable to retrieve the salesforce components.
please use this link: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000364827&type=1